# asp.net mvc Razor TextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do you check the value  that has been entered in an ASP.NET MVC @Html.TextBox and compare it with a value in the database? I want to make an easy login, and want to see if the value that has been entered in the textbox is the same as that in the database

```
<tr><td>Username</td><td>:</td><td>@Html.TextBox("username", new { @value = ViewBag.username })</td></tr>
```

I tried things like creating a viewbag and then taking it to the controller, but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: Did you try anything ? Have you searched for it ?

Comment: I tried various kinds of things, and yes, I've searched for it, but without luck, maybe my searching abilities suck.

Comment: you could have posted the things that you have tried. i mean the code

Comment: I can hardly post anything because I tried to make a class and link it to the textbox, but then I realized, how will it ever link?

Comment: A great place to start is http://asp.net/mvc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a viewmodel(a simple class) for this specific UI

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public string UserName { set;get;}

  [Required]
  [DataType(DataType.Password)]
  public string Password { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your **GET** action, create an object of this class and send to your view.

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
  var vm=new LoginViewMode();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now in our login view(Login.cshtml)which is strongly typed to our LoginViewModel, we will use the TextBoxFor html helper method to render the textboxes for our `UserName` and `Password` fields.

```
@model LoginViewModel
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
  UserName 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.UserName);

  Password
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Password)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

This will render a form which has action attribute value set to `/YourCotnroller/Login`. now we need to have an **HttpPost** action method to handle the form posting

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    string uName=model.UserName;
    string pass=model.Password.

    //Now you can use the above variables to check it against your dbrecords.  
    // If the username & password matches, you can redirect the user to 
    //  another page using RedirecToAction method
    //  return RedirecToAction("UserDashboard")

  }
  return View(model);
}
public ActionResult UserDashboard()
{
  //make sure you check whether user is logged in or not
  // to deny direct access without login
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the error when you access your GET action method ?

Comment: Sorry, I was being dumb, I forgot it was an overload action, but what do you mean with "//Now you can use the above variables to check it against your dbrecords.", because I cannot go like entity.login.username in my database.

Comment: @user1841216: you got the username/password values user entered in the variables. now you need to talk to your DB layer to get data and compare it as needed.

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to MVC, how do I compare it to my DB layer?

Comment: @user1841216 That is not an MVC specific question. It is a generic C#/ADO.NET question. Google search will give you plenty of answers.

Comment: And how do I tell it, if it's correct (the comparison) to go to a new page? do I tell that to the Beginform or to the button?

Comment: You can use `RedirectToAction` method. check my updated answer.

Comment: @user1841216: You are welcome. Glad I could help. Now enjoy the wonderful ASP.NET MVC :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Define model property in your Model class:

```
public class Login{

        [Required]
        [Remote("IsUserNameAvaliable", "Home")]
        public string username{get;set;}

        [Required]
        public string password{get;set;}
}
```

The `Remote` attribute that is placed will find the Method/Action with `IsUserNameAvaliable` in the controller name `Home`.

The remote attribute servers for this purpose in MVC.

```
public JsonResult IsUserNameAvaliable(string username)
        {
            //Check if there are any matching records for the username name provided
            if (_dbEntity.Users.Any(c => c.UserName == username))
            {
                //If there are any matching records found

                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                string userID = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                "{0} is not available.", username);

                return Json(userID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
```

Now in your view strongly type the textbox

```
@model Application.Models.Login

@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.username)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.username)
```

Donot forget to include jquery validation scripts.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't mean it like that, I don't need a JSon result, I just want to check if the textbox value is the same as in the database, thanks though ;D

Comment: yes you can check and notify whether the user is avaliable or not