# asp.net mvc textboxfor hide text for password entry

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I set the `TextBoxFor` to hide the text when user types in a password?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password.CurrentPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Current Password", autocomplete = "off", name = "nconfirm" })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Html.Password("password", "", new { id = "password", Textmode = "Password" })
```

This should help :)

Also, you can specify in your model that this is a password, like the answer in this post shows: 
[asp.net mvc Razor TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745595/asp-net-mvc-razor-textbox)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Password"})
```